# Android insert multiple rows to sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello everybody I would like to insert multiple records to my sqlite table at once,

This is what I've tried:

**DBHelper.class**

```
   public void insertToOUTTRANS(ArrayList<String> arrListDocumentNumber){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

            for(String text : arrListDocumentNumber){
                cv.put(KEY_DOCUMENTNUMBER, text);
            }
            myDataBase.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, cv, null);
        }
```

But I'm getting error in this line:

```
  myDataBase.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, cv, null);
```

Error says:

```
 The method insert(String, String, ContentValues) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, ContentValues, null)
```

**MainActivity.class:**

```
  for(int i = 0; i< arrDocumentNumber.length; i++) {
    ArrayList<String> arrListDocumentNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrListUnitOfMeasure = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrListLocationCode = new ArrayList<String>();

            arrListDocumentNumber.put(tvItemCode.getText().toString());
            arrListUnitOfMeasure.put(editText1.getText().toString));
            arrListLocationCode.put(editText1.getText().toString));

   }
```

But I'm kinda confused how to loop over the cursor to check for all items from the listview to save to my table. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` methods looks like..

```
insert(String, String, ContentValues)
```

So you need to pass `arguments` like..

```
myDataBase.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, null, cv);
```

Check `syntax` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<arrListDocumentNumber.size();i++)
{
    ContentValues initialValues=new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrListDocumentNumber.get(i));
    db.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, null, initialValues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 myDataBase.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, null, cv);
```

instead of

```
 myDataBase.insert(TBL_OUTTRANS, cv, null);
```